# Cross origin error on file/data hosted on github (gh-pages) disappears on use of custom domain

Tags: angularjs, git, github, cross-domain, github-pages

Please help me understand the cause of the following,

> problem summary: changing 'codotronix.github.io' to 'barick.in' solves Cross
>   Origin Issue

I have a json file hosted on github via gh-pages branching in the following url,
http://codotronix.github.io/bengali-recipes/data/recipe-list.json

And also, a custom domain, pointing at the same resource,
http://barick.in/bengali-recipes/data/recipe-list.json

If you click on the links above you will find that they are pointing to the same file.

But, when I am trying to get the json file from localhost, with angularjs's $http.get, 1st url is giving a cross origin error, but the 2nd one is working just fine. i.e

**This DOES NOT WORK**

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://codotronix.github.io/bengali-recipes/data/recipe-list.json')
    .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
}])
```

It gives this error ->

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://codotronix.github.io/bengali-recipes/data/recipe-list.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:55079' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**But, This One Works**

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://barick.in/bengali-recipes/data/recipe-list.json')
    .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
}])
```

And this time our `console.log` gives the expected output `Object {data: Array[19], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`

I have not set any Access-Control-Header anywhere. So, someone please explain to me why the 1st one is not working but the 2nd one is...

(Is this due to some sort of security mechanism that github has put in place? Just guessing...)

Thanks in advance.